# Queue O(1) not as fast append or pop in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, performance, queue, big-o

I made a Queue O(1) using Nodes where Queue class contain "Head and Tail" and Node Contain "Next and Back" but when I Compared "enqueue and dequeue" to " append and pop " through "timeit" I found out that " append and pop " are way faster than "enqueue and dequeue" I made.
Am I doing something wrong with   Node or Queue or my O(1) will not be as fast as append or pop ?

Comment: Built-in methods will tend to be faster than alternatives that you write yourself.

Answer (score 0):

An "arraylist" (which is the data structure behind Python's list) has an amortized cost of *O(1)* as well, so in terms of big oh, the two are equivalent. Indeed, the list has *O(n)* to append worst case, but this happens not very often. Typically the list has an initial *capacity*, and when the list is full, then it doubles the capacity. This means that if we want to make a list with *n* elements, and *n* is quite big, then the the list will be resized to capacities:

```
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, …, n
```

It each time takes the length of the original list in time to make a copy in the larger array, so that means that the total amount spent copying is the sum of these numbers, which is 2×n-1, and this *O(n)*, this thus means that *n* append, take in total *O(n)*, time, and thus the *amortized* cost of an append in a list is *O(1)*.

But there are other reasons why your linked list will be less efficient. Each time you construct a new node, it will look for a memory slot, often allocating memory takes some time. Furthermore Python's lists are typically implemented in the interpreter, for [CPython [GitHub]](https://github.com/python/cpython) for example, likely the interpreter you are using, it works with a [**`PyListObject`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c), this is often more efficient than implementing something in Python itself, since that is interpreted.